# How does PGP web of trust handle certificate expiration?

Tags: certificates, pgp, web-of-trust, expiration-date

I have certificate that expires in two years. I'll probably try to participate in key signing party so I get to know what it actually looks like.

What happens in two years? When my certificate expires, and I'll renew it by setting later expiration date. Will people still trust my certificate via the web of trust? Or will this actually change the certificate and thus invalidate all signing in the past?

How does Web Of Trust concept handle certificate expiration? I was unable to find any resources on this.